# How do I change the block size in Intel TBB's scalable_allocator?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, malloc, tbb

I'm using the scalable_allocator from the Intel Threading Building Blocks library for some HPC work.  In my use case, the scalable_allocator seems to call mmap much too often.  How do I change the size of the blocks the allocator uses?

The tbbmalloc_internal.h has a blockSize constant, but changing that had some odd effects on my system, leading me to think it might not be as simple as switching up one variable.

Comment: Which version of TBB do you use? Also, how big are typical requests to the allocator: smaller than 1K, 1K to 8K, or bigger?